# write a hierarchical query that generate specific system code in Oracle PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to write a query in Oracle PL SQL that return specific result . 
I have a hierarchical organization unit in my table . for example :

```
x ( is parent)
y (parent : x )-w ( parent : x )-z (parent : y )-u ( parent : y )-o ( parent : w )
```

I have to generate system code for this organizations like below :

```
x ( system code = 001 )- y ( system code = 001001)-w ( system code = 001002 )-z ( system code = 001001001) -u ( system code = 001001002 )-o ( system code =001002001 )
```

is there any idea ?
this link show graphical : 
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=21827544159

Comment: "is there any idea ?" No, unfortunately it is unclear what you are trying to ask. Please provide a [MCVE] including DDL and DML statements for your table and example data and a clear description of what you are trying to achieve and the expected output for your sample data and what **YOU** have attempted to solve it and where **YOUR** solution is wrong.

Comment: Oracle is a relational database. I see very little in your question that relates to a database. If you posted the table that this is stored in that might be start but you also need to show what you've tried

Comment: That linked image does not show - please do **NOT** post links to images - edit your question with the appropriate DDL and DML statements for table and your sample data and a textual summary of the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Number your data using `row_number()`, format them using `lpad()`, make hierarchical query and use `sys_connect_by_path()` to generate code:

```
select t.*, sys_connect_by_path(rn, '>') code
  from (select lpad(row_number() over (partition by pid order by id desc), 3, '0') rn,
               id, pid
          from t) t
  connect by pid = prior id
  start with pid is null
```

Use `replace(..., '>', '')` if you don't want `>` in output.

Test data:

```
create table t (id varchar2(3), pid varchar2(3));
insert into t values ('x', null);
insert into t values ('y', 'x');
insert into t values ('w', 'x');
insert into t values ('z', 'y');
insert into t values ('u', 'y');
insert into t values ('o', 'w');
```

Result:

```
RN  ID  PID CODE
--- --- --- -----------------
001 x       >001
002 w   x   >001>002
001 o   w   >001>002>001
001 y   x   >001>001
002 u   y   >001>001>002
001 z   y   >001>001>001
6 rows selected
```